# Why is the class ChangeNotifierProvider not defined?

Tags: flutter, yaml

I am trying to use the `ChangeNotifierProvider` class from [Flutter Provider package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider). However, it is given me an error saying

> The method isn't defined for the class MyCustomWidget

I have added provider dependency to my `pubspec.yaml` file.

I have a custom widget class like this

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<Name>()
}
```

Comment: Have you currently imported it, or installed a version > 2.0.0?

Comment: How do I import it? My Flutter version is 1.2.2

Answer (score 34):

Add the line in your `pubspec.yml`

```
dependencies:
flutter:
   sdk: flutter
intl: any
provider: ^5.0.0    # line to be added,don't put after sdk,it should be in 
                      flutter order
```

and then run `flutter pub get` after deleting pubspec.lock file
and

```
 import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
```

where ever is required.

Comment: Before installing, check for the latest version, new minor versions may appear weekly: https://pub.dev/packages/provider/versions#dev

Comment: I still had the error till I upgraded to the most recent version as of July 2020 `provider: ^4.3.1`

Answer (score 8):

I had to manually import the provider package (copy and paste) like the following `package:provider/provider.dart;`

Answer (score 2):

Just try running it again.
`flutter pub get`

sometimes, it does not load the dependencies.